# Splitting an array in different groups

Tags: python, numpy

Suppose I have an array with `302` elements. I want to split the array into `n = 6` groups (roughly equal size), such that it looks like the following. The following code works when `n = 6`. However, if `n` is `51` groups, then it failed and generated `60` groups. How can I get this right ?

```py
n = 6
group_num = np.arange(302) // (302 // n)
group_num[group_num == n] = n - 1
array([
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1,
    1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1,
    1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2,
    2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2,
    2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3,
    3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3,
    3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3,
    3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4,
    4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4,
    4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5,
    5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5,
    5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5],
    dtype=int32
)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`numpy.linspace`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.linspace.html):

```
n = 51
np.linspace(0, n, num=302, endpoint=False).astype(int)
```

Output:

```
array([ 0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  2,  2,  2,  2,  2,
        2,  3,  3,  3,  3,  3,  3,  4,  4,  4,  4,  4,  4,  5,  5,  5,  5,
        5,  5,  6,  6,  6,  6,  6,  6,  7,  7,  7,  7,  7,  7,  8,  8,  8,
        8,  8,  8,  9,  9,  9,  9,  9,  9, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 11, 11,
       11, 11, 11, 11, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 14, 14,
       14, 14, 14, 14, 15, 15, 15, 15, 15, 15, 16, 16, 16, 16, 16, 16, 17,
       17, 17, 17, 17, 17, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 19, 19, 19, 19, 19, 19,
       20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 21, 21, 21, 21, 21, 21, 22, 22, 22, 22, 22,
       22, 23, 23, 23, 23, 23, 23, 24, 24, 24, 24, 24, 24, 25, 25, 25, 25,
       25, 26, 26, 26, 26, 26, 26, 27, 27, 27, 27, 27, 27, 28, 28, 28, 28,
       28, 28, 29, 29, 29, 29, 29, 29, 30, 30, 30, 30, 30, 30, 31, 31, 31,
       31, 31, 31, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 33, 33, 33, 33, 33, 33, 34, 34,
       34, 34, 34, 34, 35, 35, 35, 35, 35, 35, 36, 36, 36, 36, 36, 36, 37,
       37, 37, 37, 37, 37, 38, 38, 38, 38, 38, 39, 39, 39, 39, 39, 39, 40,
       40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 41, 41, 41, 41, 41, 41, 42, 42, 42, 42, 42, 42,
       43, 43, 43, 43, 43, 43, 44, 44, 44, 44, 44, 44, 45, 45, 45, 45, 45,
       45, 46, 46, 46, 46, 46, 46, 47, 47, 47, 47, 47, 47, 48, 48, 48, 48,
       48, 48, 49, 49, 49, 49, 49, 49, 50, 50, 50, 50, 50])
```

Answer (score 0):

You are doing a floor division with `302 // n`, which will create groups that are too small. Try this:

```
import numpy

n = 51
group_num = numpy.arange(302) // (302 / n)
group_num[group_num == n] = n-1
print(group_num)
```